# sed -e undetermined `s' command

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm currently getting a `sed` error on multiple characters

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 37: unterminated `s' command
```

my sed input looks like this

```
s/EMAIL/pcorn@abc.net/;s/FULLNAME/Pop Corn/;s/TITLE/Col./;s/NAME/Corn/;s/AMOUNT/200/
s/EMAIL/pennyl@xyz.net/;s/FULLNAME/Penny Loafer/;s/TITLE/Miss/;s/NAME/Loafer/;s/AMOUNT/300/
s/EMAIL/butter@xyz.net/;s/FULLNAME/Melba Toast/;s/TITLE/Ms./;s/NAME/Toast/;s/AMOUNT/250/
s/EMAIL/bobhead@abc.com/;s/FULLNAME/Bob L Head/;s/TITLE/Mr./;s/NAME/Head/;s/AMOUNT/990/
```

where every line read from this file is a separate `sed` command.

```
template="template.txt"
details="p4Customer.txt"
count=1
filename="customer${count}.txt"

gawk -f g1.awk $details | while read detail;  #outputs the file above and pipes into while loop
    do
        sed -E $detail $template > "$directory/$filename";
        count=$(($count+1))
    done;
```

I've made sure that I used all 3 `/` and `;`. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong, maybe I've been looking at it for too long.

Comment: `char 37` is a likely clue. Just count chars from the front of your string and examine that pattern `s/str/rep/` closely. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter okay so the space is what is causing the error if I'm correct? Would `\"    \"` be the proper syntax?

Comment: what is the pattern `s/str/rep/` that contains the 37ths char? Going out for a while. I would put each `s/str/rep/` on a separate line, Something  may pop out at you. Did you write this file on Windows and the move it to LInux? If so, the `dos2unix myFixer.sed` may solve the problem. Good luck.

Comment: You don't quote your sed commands, so the shell splits them before sed ever gets to see them.

Comment: Try `sed -f cmds.sed $inputFiles | ...` (I didn't find a reference to `-E` in my `man sed` searches, did you mean `-e`?) .Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't double-quoted your variable references. Without double-quotes around them, the shell will split the variable's value into "words" (and then try to expand any file wildcards it finds in any of the words). Since your `sed` commands contain spaces, they'll be split into multiple words, which confuses `sed` completely.

Specifically, with `detail` set to "s/EMAIL/pcorn@abc.net/;s/FULLNAME/Pop Corn/;s/TITLE/Col./;s/NAME/Corn/;s/AMOUNT/200/", the command `sed -E $detail $template` is equivalent to:

```
sed -E 's/EMAIL/pcorn@abc.net/;s/FULLNAME/Pop' 'Corn/;s/TITLE/Col./;s/NAME/Corn/;s/AMOUNT/200/' template.txt
```

So `sed` tries to execute `s/EMAIL/pcorn@abc.net/;s/FULLNAME/Pop` on files named "Corn/;s/TITLE/Col./;s/NAME/Corn/;s/AMOUNT/200/" and "template.txt".

Solution: double-quote the variables:

```
sed -E "$detail" "$template" > "$directory/$filename"
```

BTW, you also don't need the `;` at the end of the line. Also, I recommend [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) for spotting basic problems like this.

There's also a logic problem in the script. You increment `count` each time through the loop, but don't update `filename`. Thus, it'll be outputting to "customer1.txt" every time through the loop. You need to either update `filename` each time through, or just include the pattern (including `$count`) in the redirect.